# List Security in Sharepoint

Tags: list, permissions, security

I need to set permissions for a list that looks like this:

I have two different teams, each with a team lead and 3 team members. The team members should not see each others data.

Team leaders have permission to see all the data of their team but should not see data from the other team.

The next level is "managers". They are able to see the data of both teams but shouldn't see other managers data.

This is the hierarchy, please help me out. One more thing I have to tell: I don't have access to our central administration, I only have my web site with full control.

---

Thanks for replay
And

I am exactly looking for..
Like I don't have permissions to go for the central admin or writing any code behind 
I have only production SharePoint site with in that I would like to provide this security levels
And I have 30 team leads every team we have 20 members 
Those 30 team leads can see their team member’s data what they entered in list, each team member should not see the others data, 
And every Team Lead should not see other Team Leads (Members of other Group) ,
Likewise I have more managers upon team leads, Managers also have the same type of permission like they can see all the data but they can’t see another manager data

How it is possible …..

Answer (score 2):

I would create two subsites (teamsites) and put permissions on site level. You can give all managers access to all subsites, well team access is limited to it's own site.

Got the feeling that this is more managable then working with lists and listpermissions.

Comment: It will not work for the same level people can you please check my question i was stuck in my project in this issue

Answer (score 1):

Either split your list into two lists, or use folders in the list, and set permission on these folders.

Another more complex way, but probably easier to use for users, is to build a workflow that setup the permissions.

Comment: how can create the copy in list , can you please check my question i was stuck in my project in this issue